# Install mcrypt on CentOS 6.2

Tags: installation, libraries, centos-6

I want to install **mcrypt** on CentOS 6.2, firstly I tried yum but it cannot fined the package, then  downloaded source file of **libmcrypt-2.5.8** compiled and installed it by following commands:

```
./configure, make, make check, make install
```

All of them successfully completed.

Then I downloaded **mcrypt-2.6.8.tar.gz**.
Now when I call `./configure` it fails with the message:

```
configure: error: libmcrypt was not found
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: I checked _usr/local/lib_ and found _libmcrypt.so.4.4.8_ on there.

Comment: First run this command `yum install libmcrypt*` and then run `./configure` this command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download `mcrypt-2.6.8.tar.gz` file

Extract the file using `tar -zxvf mcrypt-2.6.8.tar.gz`

Extracted files will be present under `mcrypt-2.6.8` directory

Change to `mcrypt-2.6.8` directory and run `./configure`

Then it will give `configure: error: *** libmcrypt was not found` error

Now run `yum install libmcrypt*` after that run `./configure`

you are done....